# "Je suis tué" meaning

Tags: grammaire, sens, temps-grammatical, passif

Does "je suis tué" mean "I am being killed", or "I am killed", that is, that I was killed and am dead or just about dead?

I would expect the answer to this question to apply to other phrases with similar constructions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Out of context, ***je suis tué*** is rare because it needs to be pronounced while being dead<sup>1</sup>. It means "**I am killed**". It can be of course be used figuratively.

"**I am being killed**" better translates to ***on me tue*** but can also use the present tense like in ***je suis tué** à petit feu par cette maladie.*

Here are other sentences where *je suis tué* can be used:

> *Je tue ou **je suis tué*** - I kill or **I am killed**.
>
> *Si **je suis tué** au combat,...* If **I'm killed** in action...

<sup>1</sup><sub>Paradoxically, ***je suis mort*** is not affected by this issue and is a common sentence.</sub>

Comment: Thank you. Is the rule that, if there is no agent in the sentence, you must use "on" and the active voice?

Comment: @CMK The problem for that reading is more the past tense than the lack of an agent -- there are awkward ways to use the passive voice for that purpose -- but in any case *on me tue* and such constructions do usually work very well.

Comment: Well, there is no distinction between continuous and non-continuous aspects in the present tense in French. One could come up with examples where the translation of *Je suis tué* uses the progressive form in English. See, for example,  the “silence” example in Laure's answer.

Comment: @LukeSawczak. Which reading are you referring to? Thanks.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez What would be considered a non-continuous aspect in the present tense in language in general?

Comment: That would mean the action is happening at a point in time. In English, non-continuous *I think you are right* vs continuous/progressive *I'm thinking about you*. Both translate to *je pense* in French. *Je pense que tu as raison* non-continuous, *je pense à toi* continuous.

Answer (score 3):

*Je suis tué* is a [passive voice](https://www.laits.utexas.edu/tex/gr/tav1.html).  If you had used any other subject pronoun than the first person I would have little hesitation on explaining the meaning of the sentence. If someone is killed (*tué*), they're deprived of life, and unless speaking from an afterlife they can't utter those words.

You are not giving the context in which you read/heard the sentence. As @jlliagre says it could be used with *si* to express a condition in which the speaker imagines they are deprived of life.

It is also likely the verb is used in a figurative way<sup>1</sup> to mean "shattered" or "strongly impressed". Like in:

> [Je suis tué de fatigue](https://books.google.fr/books?id=yvNZAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA3-PA37-IA1&lpg=RA3-PA37-IA1&dq=%22je%20suis%20tu%C3%A9%20de%20fatigue%22&source=bl&ots=YpUlbzUltj&sig=UCGK2ZXs016W3ngX5M2yOeX2FCs&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdpYS-_aHXAhXHJMAKHdH7C9kQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22je%20suis%20tu%C3%A9%20de%20fatigue%22&f=false).

It also tends to be used in place of *mort* in phrases like:

> [Je suis tué de rire](http://www.ledauphine.com/france-monde/2017/08/28/un-virus-se-propage-via-facebook-messenger) !

Here are two examples where both meanings overlap:

- In this *Je suis Charlie* [poem](http://www.printempsdespoetes.com/index.php?rub=6&ssrub=32&page=240):

  > Je suis tué nous sommes tous aujourd’hui Charlie !

  Where it takes the meaning of the actual killing in the massacre, and the moral killing of those speaking and mourning the deaths.
- Or in [David Goudreault](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Goudreault)'s [poem](http://paroles2chansons.lemonde.fr/paroles-david-goudreault/paroles-je-te-suis-tu-m-es.html):

  > Je suis tué par votre silence.

  Where the homeless who's speaking is wrecked and will eventually be destroyed because of people's indifference to his plight.

  <sup>1</sup> <sub>Just like *kill* in English</sub>

Comment: Si c'est Hamlet qui parle il y a une autre occasion encore de prononcer un tel paradoxe : "Horatio, **je suis mort**; tu vis; justifie ma cause et mon caractère auprès de ceux qui douteraient et seraient dans l'incertitude" (V-ii). :)

Comment: Thank you. I made up the sentence randomly, based on what I learned about the passive voice.